# c# how deserialize json array

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, javascriptserializer

In C# i receive a json response:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     ...
}
```

The value of result is:

```
"[\"[{\\\"retcode\\\":0}]\"]"
```

Now if i try to deserialize it into my object:

```
var myobj = js.Deserialize<List<CustomerReturnCode>>(result);
```

where:

```
public class CustomerReturnCode
{
    public string retcode { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'CustomerReturnCode'"}
```

How can i deserialize the response type? (it's an array: in this example it has only one item)

Comment: I've tried  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(result); but when deserialize i got the error: {"Invalid array passed in, ',' expected. (6): [\"[{\"retcode\":0}]\"]"}

Answer (score 0):

Your web service is returning an array of arrays. You cannot deserialize that directly because the JavascriptSerializer doesn't know how to do that.

From a discussion [here](https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/352208) it can be done using a custom JsonConverter class, using JArray.

Or I guess if you have access to modify the web service, change it to return the object in a different format.

Answer (score -1):

```
   var json="[\"[{\\\"retcode\\\":0}]\"]";
    Dynamic CRC= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<CustomerReturnCode >(json);
```

Comment: if the response contain multiple items? (it's an array)

Comment: Anyway your code raise the following error: Type 'CustomerReturnCode' is not supported for deserialization of an array."